# Serveless config - unsupported function event

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

Below is the relevant chunk of my `serverless.yml` file. When I run `serverless deploy` I get the following message:

```
Serverless: Configuration warning at 'functions.query.events[0]': unsupported function event
```

```
package:
  include:
    - handler.py
    - utils.py

functions:
  query:
    handler: handler.query
    events:
      - httpApi:  
        method: get
```

I've had this problem before and it was just a matter of indentation. Could someone point out what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Give  `method: get` another indent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in your example is caused by invalid indentation in the config - it should looks like this:

```
package:
  include:
    - handler.py
    - utils.py

functions:
  query:
    handler: handler.query
    events:
      - httpApi:  
          method: get
```

Comment: Thank you!! I also noticed I had 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces at the method definition level.